# Powershell Start-Process ignored in remote session

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, deployment, invoke-command, start-process

I am starting a new process using:

```
$removeArguments = "-Command  `"&{import-module .\deploy-utility.psm1; RemoveSolutions -solutionNames $solutionNames -url $url;}`""
start-process powershell -ArgumentList $removeArguments -Wait
```

This works fine when run locally but when run in remote session the statement is simply ignored.

I have also tried moving the command to a separate file but this makes no difference.

```
$removeArguments = "-File .\deploy-utility-functions.ps1", "remove", "$solutionNames", "$url"
$script = {start-process powershell -ArgumentList $removeArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow | Out-Host}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $script
```

Remote call:

```
$script = [scriptblock]::create("& '.\$targetFile' '$arguments'")
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $script
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can have issues with permissions in remote sessions for the second hop ( Permissions of the started process in your case). 
See enabling credssp http://ss64.com/ps/enable-wsmancredssp.html

Comment: The remote call itself is initiated and all actions up to and after Start-Process runs fine.
It is just that the Start-Process appear to be ignored.

Comment: The remote call itself, and the commands run in that session are "first hop".

Comment: Does it count as a "second hop" if the second process is started on the same machine?